# Postgresql - select query with aggregated decisions column as json

Tags: postgresql

I have table which contains specified columns:

```
id - bigint
decision - varchar(80)
type - varchar(258)
```

I want to make a select query which in result returns something like this(id, decisionsValues with counts as json, type):

```
id  decisions                                                                         type

1  {"firstDecisionsValue":countOfThisValue, "secondDecisionsValue": countOfThisValue} entryType
```

I heard that I can try play with json_agg but it does not allow COUNT method, tried to use json_agg with query:

```
SELECT ac.id,
       json_agg(ac.decision),
       ac.type
    FROM myTable ac
    GROUP BY ac.id, ac.type;
```

but ends with this(for entry with id 1 there are two occurences of firstDecisionsValue, one occurence of secondDecisionsValue):

```
id  decisions                                                             type

1  {"firstDecisionsValue", "firstDecisionsValue", "secondDecisionsValue"} entryType
```

**minimal reproducible example**

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
    id        bigint,
    decisions varchar(80),
    type      varchar(258)
);
INSERT INTO myTable
VALUES (1, 'firstDecisionsValue', 'myType');
INSERT INTO myTable
VALUES (1, 'firstDecisionsValue', 'myType');
INSERT INTO myTable
VALUES (1, 'secondDecisionsValue', 'myType');
```

**Can you provide me any tips how to make it as expected?**

```
1, {"fistDecisionsValue":2, "secondDecisionsValue":1}, entryType
```

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: @stickybit done - creation of table + inserts, desired result is provided and described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT a.id, jsonb_object_agg(a.decisions, a.count), a.type
  FROM 
     ( SELECT id, type, decisions, count(*) AS count
         FROM myTable
        GROUP BY id, type, decisions
     ) AS a
 GROUP BY a.id, a.type
```

see the result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e53c6e5b9a73fd59f67c8c278ed3551f).

Answer (score 1):

First, you should calculate the count of `id, type, decisions` for each **decisions** after that, you should use `jsonb_object_agg` to create JSON.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0427201a1e4d8ba59758a1c925ba5b15)

```sql
with data as (
select 
  ac.id,
  ac.type,
  ac.decisions,
  count(*)
from 
  myTable ac
 group by 
   ac.id, 
   ac.type,
   ac.decisions
)
select 
  d.id,
  d.type,
  json_object_agg(d.decisions, d.count)
from 
  data d
 group by 
   d.id, 
   d.type
```

Comment: Works as expected, thanks a lot :)